# CORS error when connecting to AWS elastic beanstalk API from AWS Amplify React project

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-amplify

I have a React front end hosted on AWS Amplify and express / NodeJS backend hosted on AWS elastic beanstalk.

I have this code which sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to an environment variable I have stored. On my local dev setup, this is a my localhost. But on AWS, this is the URL that my amplify site is on.

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", process.env.ALLOWED_ORIGIN);
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  next();
});
```

This works perfectly fine locally, but when I go to my site hosted on AWS amplify and try to do an API request that I built out from the front end, I get this error:
[image: cors error]

Had to block out my URLs for security, but I know that that my environment variable on elastic bean stalk is the exact same as my amplify URL, I've copied and pasted it like 7 times now.

What is going on? I would appreciate any help anyone has to offer...